# how to get FID of the user in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my database, i have one procedure which has been accessed by two other users through FID (outside of the database).

i need to log the FID of the user who are all using my procedure.

Is there any SQL Query to get the FID in oracle??

Comment: What do you mean by FID?

Comment: Functional ID to access that procedure

Comment: What's a "functional ID"? If that is something you require in your code, then you should [edit] your question and add the code of your stored procedure (or function) showing how you use that "functional ID"

Comment: FID should create one user name and grant access permission for that user name (FID) to execute that procedure..FOR EG: if the FID name is SUPPORT, user will execute my procedure through SUPPORT name.

Comment: The point is, whether you call it FID or Functional ID, this attribute is some bespoke to your application. It's not a standard Oracle thing so there is no Oracle built-in to handle it. We might be able to help you code a solution but you will need to post a lot more details before we can help.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify how exactly your users are identified (there is no "FID thing" in Oracle RDBMS). 
Oracle knows only about two layers of identification:

1. Session user (for example **scott@**). This is how to get connected user:

   ```
   select sys_context('userenv','session_user') from dual;
   ```
2. Proxy user (for example **proxy[scott]@**). This is how to get connected proxy user:

   ```
   select sys_context('userenv','proxy_user') from dual;
   ```

If your user identification is happening outside Oracle, then you can't catch it in PLSQL. You should add another IN parameter to PLSQL procedure and pass it by your outside app when calling stored procedure.